# Send email from Android App without user's intervention

Tags: android, email

I would like to send an email to given email address with some default instructions. I know that I can achieve it for sms by using twilio but don't know how to do this via mail..

Comment: Use Service instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use following to send mail with body:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                          emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                          intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String\[\]{  "serveroverloadofficial@gmail.com"});
                          intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello There");
                          intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Add Message here");


                            intent.setType("message/rfc822");

                        try {
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                    "Send email using..."));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "No email clients installed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I don't want user to select the provider, I want to send it from company's official email id through some API or some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mailgun.com](http://mailgun.com) to send email by Using their API.